# Symfony2 Guzzle store cookie for request

Tags: symfony, guzzle, guzzle6

Trying to make my Symfony2 Controller make request to backed API. Need to store the cookie received upon first API request to use it in second request.

Here is my Controller code:

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;

use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookiePlugin;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookieJar\ArrayCookieJar;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{

   public function verifyurlActionOK(Request $request)
   {


   $cookiePlugin = new CookiePlugin(new ArrayCookieJar());

   $client = new Client();

   $this->get('session')->set('client', $client);

   $client->addSubscriber($cookiePlugin);
   $request = $client->get('https://address/scanit?url='.$scantarget);
   $response = $request->send();
   }

   public function progressAction(Request $request)
   {
   $cli = $session->get('client');

   $crequest = $cli->get('https://address/progress');
   $response = $crequest->send();


   return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:progress.html.twig',
                        array(
                        'response'  => $cresponse->getBody()));
   }


}
```

Tried to set Client as a public variable in DefaultController class and as above in a Session (serialized). Both does not seem to work, here error appear on get() in the progressAction

```
[2016-11-29 16:22:46] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object"
```

How to access $client from verifyurlActionOK in progressAction??

Thanks,

Comment: the `$session` variable is not initialyzated in the `progressAction` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the progressAction method you miss to take the session from the contanier. Try adding the line `$session = $this->get('session')`

As example:

```
public function progressAction(Request $request)
   {
   $session = $this->get('session')
   $cli = $session->get('client');
```

I suggest you to store in the session the CookieJar object (it implements serializable and could be stored in the session) instead of the Client object instance. As example:

```
public function verifyurlActionOK(Request $request)
{

    $cookieJar = $this->get('session')->get('cookie-jar', new ArrayCookieJar());
    $cookiePlugin = new CookiePlugin($cookieJar);

    $client = new Client();

    $client->addSubscriber($cookiePlugin);
    $request = $client->get('https://address/scanit?url='.$scantarget);
    $response = $request->send();
    $this->get('session')->set('cookie-jar', $cookieJar);

}

public function progressAction(Request $request)
{
    $cookieJar = $this->get('session')->get('cookie-jar');
    $cookiePlugin = new CookiePlugin($cookieJar);

    $cli = new Client();

    $cli->addSubscriber($cookiePlugin);

    $crequest = $cli->get('https://address/progress');
    $response = $crequest->send();


    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:progress.html.twig',
        array(
            'response'  => $cresponse->getBody()));
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks!!! Had to upgrade to latest Guzzle, older one somehow didnt handle cookies properly. Here is also nice example how to use latest Guzzle with cookies: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#cookies

Answer (score 0):

A best practice for that is to create a shared service containing the `Client` instance and use it from both actions. Instead of storing the Client on the session, you can store the cookies.

Symfony has a good doc page on how to create services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Comment: BIG THANKS!!! After long hussle, upgraded the Guzzle to latest version (http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#cookies) and used the Jack's approach. I also like your approach, will use it in the future .... Wish I could select two answers as correct